# How to manage Windows and Ubuntu dual boot in the time of their upgrade

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, 16.10

In my laptop i dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.10. Now grub is my default boot loader.And i want some opinion on which is best for a dual boot system?

```
grub by default or
Windows boot loader by default or
Any other method to manage the dual boot in the time of their upgrade.
```

Because i will update(or upgrade) windows and ubuntu in future to the latest version.

Recently i done a ubuntu upgrade from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 16.10. But on that time i lost my default windows boot loader. And it replaced by Grub.And now grub is my default boot loader.

And previously i done windows 10 anniversary update, on that time i lost my ubuntu boot. And i restored it by EasyBCD.

Please help me.